# Aliases for limited_options in Thor

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, thor

I want to ask the user for input in Thor but have aliases:

```bash
$ Is this correct?: [yes, no, maybe] (yes)
```

Currently I have this:

```rb
class CLI < Thor
  desc 'do_thing', 'does a thing'
  def do_thing      
    answer = ask("Is this correct?", limited_to: %w{yes no maybe}, default: 'yes')
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

I would like the user to enter just the first letter of each option.

But I get this response:

```bash
$ Your response must be one of: [yes, no, maybe]. Please try again.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add aliases to `ask` as the answer will be matched directly against the list of options provided in `limited_to`. [Source](https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/v1.3.0/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb#L349)

If you really want this functionality your best bet would be skip the `limited_options` and instead check the answer after the fact and respond accordingly e.g.

```
class MyCLI  < Thor
  desc 'do_thing', 'does a thing'
  def do_thing      
    answer = ask("Is this correct? (Y)es/(N)o/(M)aybe:", default: 'Y')
    unless %w(y n m yes no maybe).include?(answer.downcase)
      puts "[#{answer}] is an invalid option. Please try again."
      send(__method__)
    end 
    puts answer
  end
end
```

Example:

```
Is this correct? (Y)es/(N)o/(M)aybe: (Y) Test 
[Test] is an invalid option. Please try again.
Is this correct? (Y)es/(N)o/(M)aybe: (Y) Yes 
Yes
```

If you want to use the built in limited options then you could use something like this but in my opinion this is not as appealing when represented in the CLI:

```
class CLI < Thor
  desc 'do_thing', 'does a thing'
  def do_thing      
    answer = ask("Is this correct? (Y)es/(N)o/(M)aybe", limited_to: %w{y n m}, default: 'y', case_insensitive: true)
  end
end
```

Which will output as:

```
Is this correct? (Y)es/(N)o/(M)aybe [y,n,m] (y)
```